# sed command to add text for only last line in unix

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed, sh

I want sed command which will add comma to only last line
e.g
 i have text file which contains

```
"872709"
"872700"
"145"
"872808B"
"8729029921"
"879B"
"87290"
"AirHo9"
"Ait22"
"DVDSept22"
"Gr929"
```

want to add comma at last line

```
"872709"
"872700"
"145"
"872808B"
"8729029921"
"879B"
"87290"
"AirHo9"
"Ait22"
"DVDSept22"
"Gr929",
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '$s/$/,/' file
"872709"
"872700"
"145"
"872808B"
"8729029921"
"879B"
"87290"
"AirHo9"
"Ait22"
"DVDSept22"
"Gr929",
```

To make it save changes inline use:

```
sed -i.bak '$s/$/,/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r '$ s/([a-zA-Z0-9"]*)/\1,/' inputfile
```

The `$` mathces the last line in the file

`([a-zA-Z0-9"]*` matches charactes numbers or " and the matched patter is saved in `\1` back reference.

`\1,` is the mathced pattern + commaa wich is the  substituion pattern

test

```
"872709"
"872700"
"145"
"872808B"
"8729029921"
"879B"
"87290"
"AirHo9"
"Ait22"
"DVDSept22"
"Gr929",
```

Comment: There's no need to substitute the whole line.

Comment: @tripleee stil in learning mode. The other answer is sweet. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

No need to use sed:

```
echo -n ',' >> file
```

Comment: That won't do what was requested if the last line of the file ends with a newline, as it likely will. The `-n` switch will prevent a newline being added *after* the comma, but what's wanted is no newline *before* it and one after it.